# Running a GEE function on Node.js provides different output

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, node-js

I'm trying to run this GEE code in Node.js

```
   var forestlayer1 = ee.Image("users/path/to/forestlayer");
   var geojson = { "type": "Polygon",
                   "coordinates": [
                       [<coordinates here>]
                   ]
       };
   
   var geojsonObject = ee.Geometry(geojson);
   
   
   var counts1 = forestlayer1.reduceRegion({
     reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
     geometry: geojsonObject,
     scale: 30
   })
   
   
   console.log(forestlayer1)
```

However, While in GEE I'm getting an acceptable result in form of JSON:

```
{
  "b1": {
    "1.0": 16.56470588235294
  }
}
```

the output in NodeJS is not the same, also I cannot find the statistic at all.

```
{
  func: {
    signature_: {
      args: [Array],
      description: 'Apply a reducer to all the pixels in a specific region.\n' +
        'Either the reducer must have the same number of inputs as the input image has bands, or it must have a single input and will be repeated for each band.\n' +
        "Returns a dictionary of the reducer's outputs.",
      returns: 'Dictionary',
      name: 'Image.reduceRegion'
    }
  },
  args: {
    image: { func: [Object], args: [Object], varName: null },
    reducer: target { func: [Object], args: {}, varName: null },
    geometry: {
      func: null,
      args: null,
      varName: null,
      type_: 'Polygon',
      coordinates_: [Array],
      geometries_: null,
      geodesic_: undefined,
      evenOdd_: undefined
    },
    scale: { func: null, args: null, varName: null, number_: 30 }
  },
  varName: null,
  dict_: null
}
```

Any tips on how to format the NodeJS output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use nodejs to run GEE processes, you need to understand that there are processes that run locally and others that run on Google's servers, you need to request the information from Google's server asynchronously using:

```
forestlayer1.getInfo(function (result){
  console.log('result: ',result)
});
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot!